# Assign leads to Users in an Object

Tags: workflow, leads, assignment-rules

I want to update the lead owner as soon as the lead is created BUT the owners are inside a SEPARATE object called skills . So I want to match the Florida leads with users inside my SKILL object which have skill florida. 
Is it possible in salesforce?

Answer (score 1):

Yes!
You need a trigger on lead with event before insert.
In your trigger business class or helper class please match respective fields.

Hope it's helpful. :)